# How to Add a Gradient in Xamarin forms Toolbar and UINavigationBar

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating a xamarin forms cross platform application for Android and iOS operating systems. I have to add a gradient to the AppBars in both Operating systems( called ToolBar in android and UINavigationBar in ios) is there any way to accomplish this. please help me cope.. with anything.

[image]

Comment: last resort is to use an image, but I highly do not recommend it.

Comment: @LeRoy do you have a idea of how to apply the image to Appbar

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should use a custom render, like this:

In your PCL or Shared Project:

```
public class NavigationPageGradientHeader : NavigationPage
{
    public NavigationPageGradientHeader(Page root) : base(root)
    {
    }
    
    public static readonly BindableProperty RightColorProperty =
      BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(RightColor),
          returnType: typeof(Color),
          declaringType: typeof(NavigationPageGradientHeader),
          defaultValue: Color.Accent);

    public static readonly BindableProperty LeftColorProperty =
       BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: nameof(LeftColor),
           returnType: typeof(Color),
           declaringType: typeof(NavigationPageGradientHeader),
           defaultValue: Color.Accent);

    public Color RightColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(RightColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RightColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public Color LeftColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(LeftColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LeftColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**[UPDATE]**

I've taken the time to create an example, you can see it in [Github](https://github.com/wilsonvargas/GradientNavigationToolbarXamarinForms).

Then in your Android project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPageGradientHeader), typeof(NavigationPageGradientHeaderRenderer))]
namespace YournameSpace.Droid
{
    public class NavigationPageGradientHeaderRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<NavigationPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            //run once when element is created
            if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            {
            return;
            }

            var control = (NavigationPageGradientHeader)this.Element;
            var context = (MainActivity)this.Context;

            context.ActionBar.SetBackgroundDrawable(new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.RightLeft, new int[] { control.RightColor.ToAndroid(), control.LeftColor.ToAndroid() }));
        }
    }
}
```

If you use `FormsAppCompatActivity` in your `MainActivity` Just add a drawable in `gradient` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >

  <gradient
      android:angle="180"
      android:centerColor="#26C986"
      android:endColor="#109F8D"
      android:startColor="#36ED81"
      android:type="linear" />

</shape>
```

Then in your `Toolbar.axml` file call this drawable:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="@drawable/gradient"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
   android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
```

And in you iOs project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPageGradientHeader), typeof(NavigationPageGradientHeaderRenderer))]
namespace YourNameSpace.iOS
{
    public class NavigationPageGradientHeaderRenderer: NavigationRenderer
    {
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            var control = (NavigationPageGradientHeader)this.Element;

            var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();
            gradientLayer.Bounds = NavigationBar.Bounds;
            gradientLayer.Colors = new CGColor[] { control.RightColor.ToCGColor(), control.LeftColor.ToCGColor() };
            gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.0, 0.5);
            gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1.0, 0.5);

            UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(gradientLayer.Bounds.Size);
            gradientLayer.RenderInContext(UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext());
            UIImage image = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            UIGraphics.EndImageContext();

            NavigationBar.SetBackgroundImage(image, UIBarMetrics.Default);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally in your `App.xaml.cs` file call this control like this:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPageGradientHeader(new MainPage()) {
     LeftColor = Color.FromHex("#109F8D"),
     RightColor = Color.FromHex("#36ED81")
};
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Wilson, I'm gonna try your solution. please tell me how to find the assembly name.

Comment: Hi @Wilson, I have tried your solution. but I got an error called `The given key was not present in the dictionary.` in the line `<controls:NavigationPageGradientHeader` . Do you have any idea?

Comment: if you could create a github project and share this.. it will give more valuable and clear too

Comment: really disappointed about the post answer response from this user

Comment: Disappointed? I was sleeping I'm not available 24 hours for you. So I've created an example that solve your problem. Please see my update

Comment: my apology. Mr wilson. thank you very much for your consideration

Comment: is it possible to have the status bar with the same gradient?

Comment: is it possible to change the NavigationBar height.??

Comment: Yes, but you should make a new question for this :)

Comment: I'll start a 200 marks bounty for this question and will accept your answer if you could help me to implement exact same UI with xamarin forms as the image i published. agree??

Comment: I have started 200 reputation bounty. given github project is not fulfill my need, please help with this..

Comment: Very claver thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue but now there is an easy way to do it using [LinearGradientBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/brushes/gradient).
Just add this to your App.xaml under :

```
   <Application.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackground">
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0"
                                         EndPoint="1,1">
                      <GradientStop Color="#26C986"
                                    Offset="0.25" />
                      <GradientStop Color="#109F8D"
                                    Offset="0.75" />             
                      <GradientStop Color="#36ED81"
                                    Offset="1.0" />
                   </LinearGradientBrush>   
                </Setter>
            </Style>
   </Application.Resources>
```

I hope that helped someone! 
Have a nice day!